# anonymous union member initialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

Use VS2017 to do code analyzing for the below codes, it always show the below warnings:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning C26495  Variable 'CB::::pA' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  ConsoleApplication3 i:\workspace\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp    20  Active

I remember it is ok to only initialize the first member of union for this case, why does vs2017 report it? In my another big vsproject, tons of this kind of warnings are reported, is there a way to waive it elegantly?

```
#include <iostream>

struct CA {
    int     a = 0;
};

struct CB {
    int b = 0;
    union {
        void*       p = nullptr;
        CA*         pA;
    };

    CB(){}

    virtual ~CB(){
        if (b == 1){
            if (pA)
                delete pA;
        }
    }

    void Test()
    {
        b = 1;
        pA = new CA;
        pA->a = 10;
        return;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    CB b;
    b.Test();
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Any settings been changed? The snippet doesn't show me the warning in VS2017 and VS2022 empty project template. Try to test it in vs2022.

Comment: Have u run the code analyzing? For example, try to press "Alt + F11" to reproduce it?

Comment: Warning C26495 appeared in VS2017 but not in VS2022.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply, Minxin, it seems that I need upgrade to VS2022, :)